# Quick Sight: Issues deleting a control

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am new to Quicksight and having an issue with deleting a filter from the controls view. I had a parameter and filter added to a visualization and deleted them but now I cannot figure how  to delete the control and not seeing the filter show up to do so. How do I remove this. I am getting the error "Filter was deleted, remove this control".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the error displayed controls in the control window. To delete, click the control and click the dot mark in the upper right corner to see the remove button.

Comment: Thank you, when I click on the control I do not see the dot mark in the upper right hand corner. I had deleted the field and no longer can see where to delete